# Get reports in Google Analytics for smart phones only (not tablets)?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

I'm trying to use Google Analytics to see how mobile phone browsers are performing on my site compared to users with larger displays. If I click the 'mobile' tab I can see goal and ecommerce performance but this includes tablets. How can I exclude tablets from my mobile reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google uses information that the browser reports, such as the user agent to work out whether it's mobile or not. You don't have access to that, so you can't draw up a list of all the user agents that belong to tablets. Even if you could that would be fiddly.

So it's better to use the screen size and also the mobile device that Google gives you and create custom segments based on that.